# How to extrapolate a GLM coefficient beyond a single unit change?

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, poisson-regression

This is a basic question but I've never seen it written down.

How can I interpret the effect on a dependent variable when there is *more than* a unit change in the independent variable for a GLM. For instance, take [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261927/poisson-regression-and-negative-binomial-regression-results-interpretation) for a model of counts of something as a function of time in years.

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = counts ~ years, init.theta = 6.190108641, link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.19350  -0.81948  -0.06559   0.47013   1.85608  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -18.316582  19.892078  -0.921    0.357
years         0.010564   0.009947   1.062    0.288

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(6.1901) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 32.207  on 29  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 31.059  on 28  degrees of freedom
AIC: 210.93

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1


              Theta:  6.19 
          Std. Err.:  2.23 

 2 x log-likelihood:  -204.928
```

As the answer says, "If you want to translate that into a percentage increase (or decrease), you subtract 1 and multiply by 100 (i.e. `(exp(0.010564)-1)*100`), so in the example that is an increase by about 1% per time unit."

**Does it follow that, if everything else is held constant, in 100 changes in time i.e. in a 100 years, there will be an approximate 100% increase in the count measure?**

Comment: No, apply the change on the log scale and then take exponentials: The estimated change for an increase of 100 years is `exp(0.010564*100)` or a factor of 2.876 or, if you wish, an increase of 187.6%.

Comment: Great, thank you. So just to solidify my understanding a negative coefficient would be `(exp(-0.010564*100)-1)*100` or -65%

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.